# Error: No overload for "Incoming" matches delegate 'SerialDataReceivedEventHandler'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make my own event for SerialPort.DataReceived in a class named Modbus, i have a windows form application and want this event fires when data is received. Here is the code:

```
public class Modbus
{
    public delegate void SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e);
    public event SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;
    static SerialPort modbusPort;

    public Modbus(int baudRate, string port)
    {
        modbusPort = new SerialPort();

        modbusPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
        modbusPort.PortName = port;
        modbusPort.Open();

        modbusPort.DataReceived += Incoming;
    }

    private void Incoming (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataReceived != null)
        {
            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs rea = new SerialDataReceivedEventArgs { Data = e.Data };
            DataReceived(this, rea);
        }
    }
}
public class SerialDataReceivedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

The error is in the line `modbusPort.DataReceived += Incoming;`

Answer (score 1):

Either `Incoming` needs to be `static` (because `modbusPort` is declared `static`), or, remove `static` from the `modbusPort` declaration. I think the latter is more appropriate here (instantiating a `static` reference in a non-static constructor is probably a smell).

What I think your code should look like:

```
public class Modbus
{
    public delegate void SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e);
    public event SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;
    private readonly SerialPort modbusPort; // CHANGED THIS LINE

    public Modbus(int baudRate, string port)
    {
        modbusPort = new SerialPort();

        modbusPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
        modbusPort.PortName = port;
        modbusPort.Open();

        modbusPort.DataReceived += Incoming;
    }

    private void Incoming (object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (DataReceived != null)
        {
            SerialDataReceivedEventArgs rea = new SerialDataReceivedEventArgs { Data = e.Data };
            DataReceived(this, rea);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i keep getting the same error. :c

Comment: You might also need to delete that first line with the `delegate` definition; `SerializeDataReceivedEventHandler` is a built-in type and you are redefining it here, which is why it may be complaining.

Comment: It doesn't work either, i have a class `SerialDataReceivedEventArgs` in the end. i modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

So after several hours i found a solution, i post the final code:

This is the code for my class

```
public class Modbus
{
    public delegate void SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args);
    public event SerialDataReceivedEventHandler DataReceived;
    private readonly SerialPort modbusPort;
    public Modbus(int baudRate, string port)
    {
        modbusPort = new SerialPort();

        modbusPort.BaudRate = baudRate;
        modbusPort.PortName = port;
        modbusPort.Open();

        modbusPort.DataReceived += Incoming;
    }
    private void Incoming(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataReceived?.Invoke(this, args);
    }
    public byte[] readE()
    {
        int size = modbusPort.ReadBufferSize;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        modbusPort.Read(buffer, 0, 1);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Code int the windows form, the next line is were i initialize the Modbus object

```
myModbus.DataReceived += Incoming;
```

And the definition

```
private void Incoming(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Byte[] indata = myModbus.readE();
    }
```